# ps segfaults on CentOS

Tags: centos, ps

I have a CentOS- 5.5 server with python2.6 installed from epel repo(disabled by default).
It keeps segfaulting. I also have maatkit from epel repo installed. In addition, am running percona as a replication slave.
i have the last few lines of strace here.(was too long for pastebin)

```
stat("/proc/17774", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
open("/proc/17774/stat", O_RDONLY)      = 6
read(6, "17774 (bash) S 17772 17774 17774"..., 1023) = 256
close(6)                                = 0
open("/proc/17774/status", O_RDONLY)    = 6
read(6, "Name:\tbash\nState:\tS (sleeping)\nS"..., 1023) = 753
close(6)                                = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 1), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2acda8509000
write(1, "  PID TTY          TIME CMD\n", 28  PID TTY          TIME CMD
) = 28
open("/proc/tty/drivers", O_RDONLY)     = 6
read(6, "/dev/tty             /dev/tty   "..., 9999) = 465
close(6)                                = 0
stat("/dev/pts1", 0x7fffaf85c6b0)       = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/dev/pts", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
readlink("/proc/17774/fd/2", "/dev/pts/1"..., 127) = 10 
stat("/dev/pts/1", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 1), ...}) = 0
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
```

not sure what is the problem with the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try remount "/dev/pts":

```
 mount -o remount /dev/pts
```

Try run python as root.

Also add "mount" output and python script/command.

Comment: Well, in between the reply and the question the whole server crashed. I sent a hardware reset and now ps works fine. am convinced it is a hardware fault. Thanks.

Comment: Just for completion, it was a faulty RAM and got it replaced finally.